# Select Option list not displaying on mobile properly and js not working as it does on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I have a form with Select Options that show and behave differently on desktop and mobile. The desired behaviour (desktop) is that all the Options are shown in the selection box, which has a size of 5, and the user clicks on the option they want. A bit of javascript then copies the selected option to a field near the submit button that says 'service selected'.

[image: desktop - on fresh load of the page]

[image: desktop - click on one of the radio buttons]

[image: desktop - select one of the services]

[image: desktop - field at the bottom is updated with the selected service]

On mobile, the options field is still at size 5 but is empty until pressed on. Then a pop up appears with the options to choose from, you can press one and it is then shown in the options field. But it doesn't then get copied to the 'service selected' field.

[image: mobile - on fresh load of page]

[image: mobile - press on one of the radio buttons]

[image: mobile - select one of the services from the pop up]

[image: mobile - select field is updated with chosen option]

[image: mobile - field at the bottom is not updated with the selected option]

I'd appreciate any pointers as at the moment I've had to just hide the form when displayed on mobiles as the 'service selected' field is used in the form submission PHP.

HTML snippet of the options:

```
<input type="radio" id="fees-section-type-ident-f" class="form-radio-input item3 expand3" name="feesType" value="Identity Confirmation" onclick="serviceSelection('ident')" <?php if (isset($_POST["feesType"]) && $_POST["feesType"] == 'Identity Confirmation') {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />
<label class="form-label form-radio-label item3" id="fees-section-type-ident-l" for="fees-section-type-ident-f">Identity Confirmation</label>
<select class="form-control form-field service-selection expanded3"id="fees-section-type-ident-options-l" name="identOptions" size="5">
  <option class="service-option-item" tabindex="0" onchange="serviceSelected()" name="identreg" value="30">£30 - Confirmation of registration</option>
  <option class="service-option-item" tabindex="0" onchange="serviceSelected()" name="identaddress" value="30">£30 - Confirmation of address</option>
</select>
```

And the field at the bottom that I want to update with the selected option:

```
<div class="radio-checkbox-column-one field-group-h-11">
  <label class="form-label field-label" id="fees-service-selected-l" for="fees-service-selected-f">Service selected:</label>
  <input class="form-control form-field" id="fees-service-selected-f" type="text" name="serviceSelected" value="<?php if(!empty($_POST["serviceSelected"])) {echo $serviceSelected;} ?>" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

JS snippet

```
//clear previous selections when changing radio button
function serviceSelection(radioid)
{
    var serviceType = document.getElementsByClassName('service-option-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < serviceType.length; i++) {
    serviceType[i].selected=0;
    }
}

function serviceSelected()
{
    var serviceItem = document.getElementsByClassName('service-option-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < serviceItem.length; i++) {
        if (serviceItem[i].selected) {
            //get the text value from the service selected
            var service = serviceItem[i].text;
            //update the service choice with the service text
            var choice = document.getElementById('fees-service-selected-f');
            choice.text = service; //testing
        }
    }   
}
```

Edit: I changed the Options from onclick to onchange, but it didn't help.

Comment: you really should be using onchange on the select element, not click events on the options.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually got a different function for the Select onclick that deselects all options previously selected...