# Difference in Javascript on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, mobile

I raised this six months ago here: [link to previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75723112/select-option-list-not-displaying-on-mobile-properly-and-js-not-working-as-it-do?noredirect=1#comment133582906_75723112)

My html is different in that I've removed the onclick/onchange events and I've changed the javascript to create event listeners instead:

```
//clear previous selections when changing radio button

var elementsFeesType = document.forms['fees-form'].elements['feesType'];

var serviceSelection = function(){
    var serviceType = document.getElementsByClassName('service-option-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < serviceType.length; i++) {
    serviceType[i].selected="";
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < elementsFeesType.length; i++) {
    elementsFeesType[i].addEventListener('click', serviceSelection, false);
    elementsFeesType[i].addEventListener('change', serviceSelection, false);
}

//show the relevant option selected in the field at the bottom

var elementsServiceOptionItem = document.forms['fees-form'].querySelectorAll('.service-option-item');

var serviceSelected = function() {
    var serviceItem = elementsServiceOptionItem; // Avoid redundant DOM query
    for (var j = 0; j < serviceItem.length; j++) {
        if (serviceItem[j].selected) {
            var value = serviceItem[j].value;
            var service = serviceItem[j].text;
            var choice = document.getElementById('fees-service-selected-f');
            choice.value = value;
            choice.text = service;
        }
    }
};

for (var j = 0; j < elementsServiceOptionItem.length; j++) {
    // Use 'change' event listener if you only want to trigger on change
    elementsServiceOptionItem[j].addEventListener('click', serviceSelected, false);
    elementsServiceOptionItem[j].addEventListener('change', serviceSelected, false);
}

//toggle the sick note fields

var toggleSection = function(selectedItem) {
    var selectedOption = selectedItem.value;
    var expanded4a = document.querySelector(".expanded4a");
    var expanded4b = document.querySelector(".expanded4b");

    expanded4a.style.display = "none";
    expanded4b.style.display = "none";

    if (selectedOption === "Sick Note") {
        expanded4a.style.display = "grid";
        expanded4b.style.display = "none";
    } else if (selectedOption === "Fit Note") {
        expanded4a.style.display = "none";
        expanded4b.style.display = "grid";
    }
};

for (var k = 0; k < elementsServiceOptionItem.length; k++) {
    
    elementsServiceOptionItem[k].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        toggleSection(event.target); // Pass the clicked element as an argument
    }, false);
    elementsServiceOptionItem[k].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        toggleSection(event.target); // Pass the changed element as an argument
    }, false);
}
```

But I still can't get it to work on mobiles and am tearing my hair out. I think it's do with Select/Options and the way they are treated or something on mobiles. I've tried 'click', 'change', 'touchend'... all to no avail.

What I'm trying to do is get an event to fire when an Option is selected (that event is to open another div with more fields in it).

Before I completely redesign the form to have a list of 16 radio buttons, instead of 5 radio buttons that each contain relevant options in them, does anyone have a suggestion please?

A kind one, if possible.

Comment: without being able to see the full code and the specific issue you're facing, it's difficult to pinpoint the problem.